# react-select resolve option based on id

Tags: javascript, initialization, jquery-select2, react-select

For select2 library, there was an option called `initSelection` which would enable users to resolve the label based on the selected value.

Is there something similar for react-select ?

Answer (score 0):

The onChange prop of the react-select gets called with the selected option. Which is an object and has the label and the value of the selection, just like in example of the component.

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#usage

Save the label to state and use it where you like.
The example logs the selected option's label to console. Check it out.